# HtmlAgilityPack Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, web-crawler

Got a problem with Html Agility Pack
When I run my code it says "Unable to connect to the remote server"
Does anybody know why?

Here is the code:

```
public void Crawler(string url, int pid)
{
    HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    try
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='metatag-topi metatag-keywords']");
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='pagination']/a[@href]");
        HtmlNodeCollection phone = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='phone fRight ml10']");
```

Html Code:

```
<h2 class="header">
<a class="metatag-topic metatag-keywords" title="" href="/Directory/d.482"> ادارات، سازمان ها و تشکیلات</a>
</h2>
```

Comment: Is your URL actually working? The issue would be on the hw.Load(url) part.

Comment: Proxy server? Do you need to authenticate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set application pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401479/how-to-set-application-pool)